# Storing jQuery variables in Rails cookies

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, cookies

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to post jQuery variables to a Rails cookie.

I want to store two jQuery variables when any user visits the page.

I've got a bit of Ajax making the post, thus:

```
/$.post('/where', {var1: one, var2: two});
```

I'm just not wholly sure how to set up the '/where' part.

Any help would be great!

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of posting directly to a Rails cookie, you should post to the "/where" url, which calls a controller action. In the action, you can set the cookies.

For example,

in your routes, declare:

```
post "/where", :to => "whatever#where"
```

in your controller:

```
class WhateverController < ApplicationController

  def where

    session[:var1] = params[:var1]
    session[:var2] = params[:var2]

    ...
    render :nothing => true //if you don't want to render anything
  end

 end
```

If that's not what you're looking for, can you elaborate more in your question?